# C++ library files not identifying from IIS

Tags: wcf, dll, iis-7

I am having some C++ library(.dll) file, have to use in WCF webservice. Normally WCF can understand only the dll located at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\DevServer\11.0`. I successfully run and call the dll through code. But after hosted in IIS, IIS cannot locate the dll files, it's unable to load assemblies. What is the exact location to put dll files in IIS?

Comment: Why don't you put your dll where your executable is?

Comment: Initially i put only in wcf application folder,But it cant able to load.I searched in Google for that ,IT says WCF application can read thrid party dll, only if the location is  C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\DevServer\11.0. so only i put .

Comment: Please post your code. How do you reference the native dll in your code?

Answer (score 0):

Don't refer the dlls from a physical path in your local drive. If you did then the dlls will be in your local and only the service will be moved to the server. So, place a folder within your application and place the dlls within that folder and refer them. So, while moving the service solution the dlls will also move along with the solution.

```
If the dlls are owned by any other tools or applications then you need to install them in that server where you are planning to host the service. If you need only the dlls and they can  work independently then you may copy the dlls as said above.
```

Comment: Unable to load Assembly files came

Comment: The service is trying to access the dlls from GAC. Please add the dlls to the GAC. Then update the config file with the required dlls as following

<compilation debug="true">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="MyWcfAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=AAAAAAAAAA"/>

Answer (score -1):

The service is trying to access the dlls from GAC. Please add the dlls to the GAC. Then update the config file with the required dlls as following

```
    <compilation debug="true">
       <assemblies>
         <add assembly="MyWcfAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,     PublicKeyToken=AAAAAAAAAA"/>
       </assembly>
     </compilation>
```

Comment: Please read the question. It's a native dll, you cannot load that into the GAC.